# Reference request: Construction of $M_{1,0}$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Does anyone know a reference for the construction of the (Artin) stack $M_{1,0}$ and a result about the corresponding coarse moduli space? In Deligne-Mumford they construct $M_{g,0}$ when $g\geq 2$ and the corresponding coarse moduli space.

Comment: I think this gadget is an Artin stack. Have you looked into where these were first introduced (presumably a paper of Artin but who knows when it comes to mathematical nomenclature)? Otherwise I would suggest digging around in The Stacks Project, although I would imagine that in there the stack $\mathfrak M_{g,n}$ of curves without any kind of stability condition is constructed for all $g,n \ge 0$ or something very general like that. OTOH I think there is a sort of "introductory" document specifically about moduli of elliptic curves that is floating around somewhere in The Stacks Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can check *Geometry of Algebraic Curves* from Arbarello et al.

Comment: Unless I'm looking at the wrong part it looks like they only informally construct the coarse moduli space of $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. I was looking for something more global, at least over an arbitrary algebraically closed field $k$, and also for $\mathcal{M}_{1,0}$ rather than $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$. I have families of genus one curves which might not necessarily have a section.